# jQuery KendoEditor not stripping pasted HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, kendo-ui, kendo-editor

I have a page where I am using an instance of a KendoEditor. The editor should have very limited functionality and allow only `strong`, `ul`, `li`, `ol`, and `p` HTML tags inside of its content. Whenever I paste a whole web page into the editor it gets pasted along with all HTML tags of that page.

I tried filtering these out using a mix of **pasteCleanup** attribute of KendoEditor and regular expressions like so:

```
pasteCleanup: {
    css: true,
    span: true,
    msAllFormatting: true,
    msConvertLists: true,
    msTags: true,
    keepNewLines: true,
    custom: function (html) {
        return html.replace(/<\/?(?!strong)(?!ul)(?!li)(?!ol)(?!p)\w*\b[^>]*>/, "");
    }
},
```

But even if I set all: true on pasteCleanup this still retains span `style="font-size: something"`, font and headings (`h1`,`h2` ...etc) tags. I also tried parsing it manually on paste event of KendoEditor:

```
paste: function(e) {
  $(".text-editor").find("*").not("strong,ul,li,ol,p").each(function() {
    $(this).replaceWith(this.innerHTML);
  });
},
```

I tried targetting both the `textarea` of the editor, as well as Iframe containing the displayed text but this has absolutely no effect. My assumption is that paste fires before the content even gets rendered. I also tried just about all the combinations of **pasteCleanup** you can imagine thinking that some of these props might conflict with one another. Any idea?

example pasted page: https://html.nicole-wellinger.ch/schrift/txtgroesse.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot about one little but important detail: The [JavaScript modifier](https://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html) `g`. You might want to consider `i` for case insensitivity as well.

Comment: You are correct. I was missing the global flag on the regex after all. Thanks

Comment: Don't forget: you can accept this answer if it was the correct or useful solution. Read more about accepting answers on https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

for me this is the one its worked

```
                pasteCleanup: {
                custom: function (html)
                {
                    html = html.replace(/<\s*br\/*>/gi, '');
                    html = html.replace(/<\s*a.*href="(.*?)".*>(.*?)<\/a>/gi, " $2 (Link - $1) ");
                    html = html.replace(/<\s*\/*.+?>/ig, '');
                    html = html.replace(/ {2,}/gi, '');
                    html = html.replace(/\n+\s*/gi, '');
                    html = html.replace("&nbsp;", '');
                    html = html.replace(/&lt;.*?&gt;/g, '');
                    return html;
                }
            }
```